# onActivityResult not working after other activity call other activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult

I have a problem when I use startactivityforresult,, I have two conditions on this issue

```
1. activity A -> activity B = onActivityResult in activity A called //success
2. activity A -> activity B -> Call Camera = onActivityResult called only in Activity B, activity A isn't called
```

I use this code in activity A

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
           if(resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED){
                 Bundle b = data.getExtras(); 
                 String data = b.getString("data");                      
             }
    }
```

in activity B

```
   String fileName;
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            selectedPath=getPath(data.getData());
            File source= new File(selectedPath);
            fileName=source.getName();                   
         }
    }
```

in activity B i have button to finish activity B and then calling back activity A with bring value `fileName`
here the code

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
              Intent i = new Intent();
              i.putExtra("data", fileName);
              setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
              finish();
            }
});
```

I want to return value of the `activity B` from `activity A` after activity B ever `call camera intent` (in case 2)?

how I achieve that ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you called setResult(RESULT_OK) on activity B and wrap the data in the intent before finish()?

Answer (score 0):

After calling camera, `onActivityResult()` will be called on `activity B` instead of `activity A` because it was the activity who called the camera, not activity A. Simply override `onActivityResult()` in activity B and call `setResult()` to propagate the result to activity A.